# Create OWL-File based on data from triple store

Tags: rdf, owl, triplestore

I have basically a triple store in a mongoDB: It is a huge collection of data where every row contains an entry for "subject", "property" and "object". The collection was created by parsing an OWL-file.

After users have modified this database, I want to write a modified OWL-file based on this triple store.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

To get an Idea of the data I am talking about, here is an entry:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("60f54396c15008676831ad9c"),
"s" : "http://knowrob.org/kb/knowrob.owl#actor",
"p" : "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subPropertyOf",
"o" : "http://www.ontologydesignpatterns.org/ont/dul/DUL.owl#hasParticipant"
```

I want to create an OWL-file out of this in order to feed it to an OWL-reasoner like HermiT.

Comment: So you want to "reconvert" it in OWL?

Comment: "Suggestions" for what? What is the problem?

Comment: correct, I want to "reconvert" it in OWL

Comment: A lot depends on desired format, language and libraries you plan to use. If, for example, ntriples is good enough for you and your subjects are named resources, you can easily create a file simply outputting the triples with some syntactic sugar to match the ntriples format. You should elaborate on any constraints/choices about these, or the answers will not be very useful to you.

Comment: having triples in your MongoDB what speaks against simply writing the data as N-Triples? I mean, this is the most simple format of all formats

Comment: @Ignazio I updated my question to be more specific. I want the OWL-file as input for HermiT or a similar reasoner

Comment: it doesn't matter. Just write the triples as N-Triples format, this is the easiest format.

Comment: hm can HermiT read N-Triple format? I thought it is limited to XML format...

Comment: HermiT does use OWL API for parsing, and OWL API does allow to load the ontologies in any format, especially also in Turtle and N-Triples is a subset of Turtle syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is with Python's RDFLib. The idea is to pull each record out of the relational database, insert it into rdflib's in memory graph store, and then export the rdflib store to disk which you can then use with  HermiT.

```
import rdflib

graph = rdflib.Graph()

For each database entry:
   graph.add((s, p, o))

g.serialize(destination='graph.ttl', format='turtle')
```